# How to create Combobox array in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, combobox

I have an input `n=5`, so can I create 5 `Combobox` and combine them together to something like an array?
I just want to get the value of each Combobox through its index `i` just like `box[i].get()`.

Help me with this, please!

Comment: Yes you can? Using a ```for``` loop?

Comment: `boxes = [Combobox(<arguments>) for _ in range(n)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
x=int(input("Enter number of Comboboxes: "))
root=Tk()
box_dict={}
def change_icon( event, j):
    print("-------------------------")
    
    print ("Value: ",box_dict[j].get(),f"at Combobox: {box_dict[j]}")
for i in range(x):
    
    Label(root,text=f"Combobox Number: {i}").pack()
    box=ttk.Combobox(root,state="readonly",values=['1','2','3','4'])
    box_dict[i] = box
    box.pack()
    box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",lambda event, j=i: change_icon(event, j))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Combobox is a combination of Listbox and an entry field. It is one of the Tkinter widgets where it contains a down arrow to select from a list of options. It helps the users to select according to the list of options displayed. When the user clicks on the drop-down arrow on the entry field, a pop up of the scrolled Listbox is displayed down the entry field. The selected option will be displayed in the entry field only when an option from the Listbox is selected.

Syntax:

combobox = ttk.Combobox(master, option=value, ...)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Listbox widget for the combobox.Below is the example of autocomplete combobox in python Tkinter.

```
def checkkey(event):
   
value = event.widget.get()
print(value)
  
# get data from l
if value == '':
    data = l
else:
    data = []
    for item in l:
        if value.lower() in item.lower():
            data.append(item)
update(data)
def update(data):
  
# clear previous data
lb.delete(0, 'end')

# put new data
for item in data:
    lb.insert('end', item)
l = ('C','C++','Java',
 'Python','Perl',
 'PHP','ASP','JS' )
root = Tk()


e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<KeyRelease>', checkkey)


lb = Listbox(root)
lb.pack()
update(l)

root.mainloop()
```